# Sorting pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1, 188],
    [1, 258],
    [1, 386],
    [1, 385],
    [1, 386],
    [2, 111],
    [2, 253],
    [2, 812],
    [3, 936],
    [3, 121],
    [3, 273],
    [3, 554],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Num', 'Val'])
print(df)
```

What would be the best way to create a new DF in which the columns represent the following statistics for each 'Num' group:

```
 Val First - the first value of a certain Num in the list;
 Val Last - the last value of a certain Num in the list; 
 Val Min - the minimum value of a certain Num in the list;
 Val Max - the maximum value of a certain Num in the list.
```

Expecting output:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({
    'Num': [1, 2, 3],
    'Val First': [188, 111, 936],
    'Val Last': [386, 812, 554],
    'Val Min': [188, 111, 121],
    'Val Max': [386, 812, 936]
})

df_new.columns = ["Num", "Val First", "Val Last", "Val Min", "Val Max"]

print(df_new)
```

I will be grateful for your help and maybe it will help other people learn to work with pandas faster...

I tried to manage this by using:

```
df_new = df.groupby('Num').agg({'Val': ['min', 'max']})
```

To find Val Min and Val Max for each Num group, but I can't figure out how to determine the standing on the edges elements for each group (Val First and Val Last).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`df.groupby().agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) and assigning new column names

```py
df_new = df.groupby('Num').agg({'Val': ['first', 'last', 'min', 'max']})
df_new.columns = ['Val First', 'Val Last', 'Val Min', 'Val Max']
df_new.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(df_new)
```

---

```
   Num  Val First  Val Last  Val Min  Val Max
0    1        188       386      188      386
1    2        111       812      111      812
2    3        936       554      121      936
```

You can also use the `**` approach to assign the columns in `agg()`

```py
df_new = df.groupby('Num').agg(
    **{
       'Val First': ('Val', 'first'),
       'Val Last': ('Val', 'last'),
       'Val Min': ('Val', 'min'),
       'Val Min': ('Val', 'max')
    }).reset_index()

print(df_new)
```